# Potential Issue With Getting Hard Drive Serial From a RAID configuration

Tags: c#, .net, virtual-machine, identity

I currently have a function that returns the hard drive serial of a virtual machine using calls via WMI, which works great when run on an actual physical hard drive. However, when I run the function on a virtual machine with a virtual disk, the hard drive serial always comes back as the same series of 1's and 0's. I am trying to use this technique to identify a specific machine. Is there a more reliable way to retrieve some sort of identifier which identifies the hardware used in a (virtual) machine that will likely not change?

As a note, I have had the MAC Address given to me as a suggestion, but I do not want my software to break if the NIC it is bound to has to be replaced.

I am also concerned with what might return on a system hard drive which is configured via RAID, as this serial needs to be consistent with every call. I do not have a RAID configured system to test this on, however, so I am unsure of what will even be returned in the first place.

***EDIT*** I have figured out a reliable way to lock our software to a virtual machine even if the serial number might not be unique, so the VM portion is no longer an issue. However, I still am unsure of how this might return on with certain RAID configurations, and as stated above, I do not have the luxury of a RAID configured machine to test on, much less several configurations to test. Any assistance on this is very much appreciated.

Here is the HD serial function:

```
string Win32_Class = string.Empty;
string Win32_Property = string.Empty;
string systemDrive = null;
try
{
    systemDrive = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.System).Substring(0, 2);
    Win32_Class = "Win32_LogicalDisk";
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(string.Format("SELECT * FROM {1} WHERE DeviceID='{0}'", systemDrive, Win32_Class)))
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject logicalDisk in searcher.Get())
        {
            Win32_Class = "Win32_DiskPartition";
            foreach (ManagementObject partition in logicalDisk.GetRelated(Win32_Class))
            {
                Win32_Class = "Win32_DiskDrive";
                foreach (ManagementObject diskDrive in partition.GetRelated(Win32_Class))
                {
                    Win32_Class = "Win32_PhysicalMedia";
                    foreach (ManagementObject diskMedia in diskDrive.GetRelated(Win32_Class))
                    {
                        Win32_Property = "SerialNumber";
                        mySystemDeviceSerial = diskMedia[Win32_Property].ToString().Trim();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the VM is moved to another physical machine and run, do you expect the SerialNumber to remain the same or change?

Comment: Actually, I've figured out that this won't matter anyways in the case of a VM. I do need to know if/which RAID configurations might produce inconsistent results though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the serial number of the 'logical' disk. This will change if the disk is repartitioned. If one drive of a redundant RAID setup is changed it won't change. This is something stored at the block level so it won't matter what the actual storage setup is.

You want the `VolumeSerialNumber` property of a `Win32_LogicalDisk` for the installation volume.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: i do have one question on this, if the partition is modified, the serial isn't changed right?

Comment: I don't think so no, but I'd have to check to be certain.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to identify the VM instance, you could use the UUID property of the `Win32_ComputerSystemProduct` instance. In the real world, this maps to an ID on the motherboard. In a VM, this returns a unique value for each VM configuration, regardless of the drives (but I'm not sure what happens if the VM is cloned or moved).

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'll look into this avenue and this could be something I incorporate in the next version of our product